# How can I wrap AND truncate axis labels via ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, axis, stringr

My axis labels on a column graph are unreasonably long. Initially, I addressed this via `stringr` thanks to [dibisan's solution on an existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17858465/how-can-i-shorten-x-axis-label-text-in-ggplot) which allowed me to truncate the labels using the following code:

```
ig_plot + scale_x_discrete(label = function(x) str_trunc(x, width = 40)) +
          theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, vjust = 1))
```

[Plot with truncated labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCpCL.png)

I then decided that I wanted to show more characters, and found [Sandy Muspratt's solution to an existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878974/wrap-long-axis-labels-via-labeller-label-wrap-in-ggplot2), using `str_wrap`:

```
ig_plot + scale_x_discrete(label = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 30)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, vjust = 1))
```

[Plot with wrapped labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZE20z.png)

This second plot is more similar to what I want to display. However, it has too many characters. I want to wrap the labels so that each label is 2 lines of 30 characters, followed by ellipses representing excess characters.

I have tried combining both `str_trunc` and `str_wrap` within the `scale_x_discrete` function as below:

```
ig_plot + scale_x_discrete(label = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 30),
                                              str_trunc(x,60)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, vjust = 1))
```

This does not work and generates the error: `Error in str_trunc(x, 60) : object 'x' not found`.

I had also tried combining as a separate geom, but this results only in the truncation:

```
ig_plot + scale_x_discrete(label = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 30)) +
  scale_x_discrete(label = function(x) str_trunc(x, width = 60)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, vjust = 1))
```

Can someone please help write an expression to truncate to 60 characters, while line-breaking at 20? Ideally using `stringr` (though other solutions appreciated too!).

Code for `ig_plot`:

```
ig_plot <- ggplot(ig_protein_long, 
                  aes(x = Protein.names, 
                      y = Abundance,
                      fill = Sample)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge2")
```

Data:

```
Protein.names                                                                                                                                                    Protein.Names2 Sample        Abundance
   <chr>                                                                                                                                                            <chr>          <chr>             <dbl>
 1 Immunoglobulin heavy constant gamma 1 (Ig gamma-1 chain C region) (Ig gamma-1 chain C region EU) (Ig gamma-1 chain C region KOL) (Ig gamma-1 chain C region NIE) IGHG1_HUMAN    2_1A            5864380
 2 Immunoglobulin heavy constant gamma 1 (Ig gamma-1 chain C region) (Ig gamma-1 chain C region EU) (Ig gamma-1 chain C region KOL) (Ig gamma-1 chain C region NIE) IGHG1_HUMAN    2_1A_deglycos   4048260
 3 Immunoglobulin heavy constant gamma 1 (Ig gamma-1 chain C region) (Ig gamma-1 chain C region EU) (Ig gamma-1 chain C region KOL) (Ig gamma-1 chain C region NIE) IGHG1_HUMAN    2_1D            5688230
 4 Immunoglobulin heavy constant gamma 1 (Ig gamma-1 chain C region) (Ig gamma-1 chain C region EU) (Ig gamma-1 chain C region KOL) (Ig gamma-1 chain C region NIE) IGHG1_HUMAN    2_1D_deglycos   3701410
 5 Immunoglobulin heavy constant gamma 1 (Ig gamma-1 chain C region) (Ig gamma-1 chain C region EU) (Ig gamma-1 chain C region KOL) (Ig gamma-1 chain C region NIE) IGHG1_HUMAN    AED5            8264160
 6 Immunoglobulin heavy constant gamma 1 (Ig gamma-1 chain C region) (Ig gamma-1 chain C region EU) (Ig gamma-1 chain C region KOL) (Ig gamma-1 chain C region NIE) IGHG1_HUMAN    AED5_deglycos   7439780
 7 Immunoglobulin heavy constant gamma 1 (Ig gamma-1 chain C region) (Ig gamma-1 chain C region EU) (Ig gamma-1 chain C region KOL) (Ig gamma-1 chain C region NIE) IGHG1_HUMAN    AI5             1189120
 8 Immunoglobulin heavy constant gamma 1 (Ig gamma-1 chain C region) (Ig gamma-1 chain C region EU) (Ig gamma-1 chain C region KOL) (Ig gamma-1 chain C region NIE) IGHG1_HUMAN    AI5_deglycos    1179410
 9 Immunoglobulin heavy constant gamma 3 (HDC) (Heavy chain disease protein) (Ig gamma-3 chain C region)                                                            IGHG3_HUMAN    2_1A             625329
10 Immunoglobulin heavy constant gamma 3 (HDC) (Heavy chain disease protein) (Ig gamma-3 chain C region)                                                            IGHG3_HUMAN    2_1A_deglycos    717111
11 Immunoglobulin heavy constant gamma 3 (HDC) (Heavy chain disease protein) (Ig gamma-3 chain C region)                                                            IGHG3_HUMAN    2_1D             592491
12 Immunoglobulin heavy constant gamma 3 (HDC) (Heavy chain disease protein) (Ig gamma-3 chain C region)                                                            IGHG3_HUMAN    2_1D_deglycos    651356
13 Immunoglobulin heavy constant gamma 3 (HDC) (Heavy chain disease protein) (Ig gamma-3 chain C region)                                                            IGHG3_HUMAN    AED5                 NA
14 Immunoglobulin heavy constant gamma 3 (HDC) (Heavy chain disease protein) (Ig gamma-3 chain C region)                                                            IGHG3_HUMAN    AED5_deglycos    203275
15 Immunoglobulin heavy constant gamma 3 (HDC) (Heavy chain disease protein) (Ig gamma-3 chain C region)                                                            IGHG3_HUMAN    AI5                  NA
16 Immunoglobulin heavy constant gamma 3 (HDC) (Heavy chain disease protein) (Ig gamma-3 chain C region)                                                            IGHG3_HUMAN    AI5_deglycos         NA
17 Immunoglobulin heavy constant gamma 4 (Ig gamma-4 chain C region)                                                                                                IGHG4_HUMAN    2_1A             957383
18 Immunoglobulin heavy constant gamma 4 (Ig gamma-4 chain C region)                                                                                                IGHG4_HUMAN    2_1A_deglycos    804135
19 Immunoglobulin heavy constant gamma 4 (Ig gamma-4 chain C region)                                                                                                IGHG4_HUMAN    2_1D             984904
20 Immunoglobulin heavy constant gamma 4 (Ig gamma-4 chain C region)                                                                                                IGHG4_HUMAN    2_1D_deglycos    645221
21 Immunoglobulin heavy constant gamma 4 (Ig gamma-4 chain C region)                                                                                                IGHG4_HUMAN    AED5            2239410
22 Immunoglobulin heavy constant gamma 4 (Ig gamma-4 chain C region)                                                                                                IGHG4_HUMAN    AED5_deglycos   2265830
23 Immunoglobulin heavy constant gamma 4 (Ig gamma-4 chain C region)                                                                                                IGHG4_HUMAN    AI5              283809
24 Immunoglobulin heavy constant gamma 4 (Ig gamma-4 chain C region)                                                                                                IGHG4_HUMAN    AI5_deglycos     176392
25 Immunoglobulin heavy constant mu (Ig mu chain C region) (Ig mu chain C region BOT) (Ig mu chain C region GAL) (Ig mu chain C region OU)                          IGHM_HUMAN     2_1A            1819170
26 Immunoglobulin heavy constant mu (Ig mu chain C region) (Ig mu chain C region BOT) (Ig mu chain C region GAL) (Ig mu chain C region OU)                          IGHM_HUMAN     2_1A_deglycos   1617100
27 Immunoglobulin heavy constant mu (Ig mu chain C region) (Ig mu chain C region BOT) (Ig mu chain C region GAL) (Ig mu chain C region OU)                          IGHM_HUMAN     2_1D            1904510
28 Immunoglobulin heavy constant mu (Ig mu chain C region) (Ig mu chain C region BOT) (Ig mu chain C region GAL) (Ig mu chain C region OU)                          IGHM_HUMAN     2_1D_deglycos   1260750
29 Immunoglobulin heavy constant mu (Ig mu chain C region) (Ig mu chain C region BOT) (Ig mu chain C region GAL) (Ig mu chain C region OU)                          IGHM_HUMAN     AED5            7667500
30 Immunoglobulin heavy constant mu (Ig mu chain C region) (Ig mu chain C region BOT) (Ig mu chain C region GAL) (Ig mu chain C region OU)                          IGHM_HUMAN     AED5_deglycos   7660800
31 Immunoglobulin heavy constant mu (Ig mu chain C region) (Ig mu chain C region BOT) (Ig mu chain C region GAL) (Ig mu chain C region OU)                          IGHM_HUMAN     AI5              366542
32 Immunoglobulin heavy constant mu (Ig mu chain C region) (Ig mu chain C region BOT) (Ig mu chain C region GAL) (Ig mu chain C region OU)                          IGHM_HUMAN     AI5_deglycos     494940
33 Immunoglobulin heavy constant alpha 1 (Ig alpha-1 chain C region) (Ig alpha-1 chain C region BUR) (Ig alpha-1 chain C region TRO)                                IGHA1_HUMAN    2_1A           38816100
34 Immunoglobulin heavy constant alpha 1 (Ig alpha-1 chain C region) (Ig alpha-1 chain C region BUR) (Ig alpha-1 chain C region TRO)                                IGHA1_HUMAN    2_1A_deglycos  25503900
35 Immunoglobulin heavy constant alpha 1 (Ig alpha-1 chain C region) (Ig alpha-1 chain C region BUR) (Ig alpha-1 chain C region TRO)                                IGHA1_HUMAN    2_1D           42940400
36 Immunoglobulin heavy constant alpha 1 (Ig alpha-1 chain C region) (Ig alpha-1 chain C region BUR) (Ig alpha-1 chain C region TRO)                                IGHA1_HUMAN    2_1D_deglycos  23146300
37 Immunoglobulin heavy constant alpha 1 (Ig alpha-1 chain C region) (Ig alpha-1 chain C region BUR) (Ig alpha-1 chain C region TRO)                                IGHA1_HUMAN    AED5          114771000
38 Immunoglobulin heavy constant alpha 1 (Ig alpha-1 chain C region) (Ig alpha-1 chain C region BUR) (Ig alpha-1 chain C region TRO)                                IGHA1_HUMAN    AED5_deglycos 105117000
39 Immunoglobulin heavy constant alpha 1 (Ig alpha-1 chain C region) (Ig alpha-1 chain C region BUR) (Ig alpha-1 chain C region TRO)                                IGHA1_HUMAN    AI5            56312200
40 Immunoglobulin heavy constant alpha 1 (Ig alpha-1 chain C region) (Ig alpha-1 chain C region BUR) (Ig alpha-1 chain C region TRO)                                IGHA1_HUMAN    AI5_deglycos   56323800
41 Immunoglobulin heavy constant alpha 2 (Ig alpha-2 chain C region) (Ig alpha-2 chain C region BUT) (Ig alpha-2 chain C region LAN)                                IGHA2_HUMAN    2_1A            6839840
42 Immunoglobulin heavy constant alpha 2 (Ig alpha-2 chain C region) (Ig alpha-2 chain C region BUT) (Ig alpha-2 chain C region LAN)                                IGHA2_HUMAN    2_1A_deglycos   3586850
43 Immunoglobulin heavy constant alpha 2 (Ig alpha-2 chain C region) (Ig alpha-2 chain C region BUT) (Ig alpha-2 chain C region LAN)                                IGHA2_HUMAN    2_1D            5939300
44 Immunoglobulin heavy constant alpha 2 (Ig alpha-2 chain C region) (Ig alpha-2 chain C region BUT) (Ig alpha-2 chain C region LAN)                                IGHA2_HUMAN    2_1D_deglycos   3094120
45 Immunoglobulin heavy constant alpha 2 (Ig alpha-2 chain C region) (Ig alpha-2 chain C region BUT) (Ig alpha-2 chain C region LAN)                                IGHA2_HUMAN    AED5           26295900
46 Immunoglobulin heavy constant alpha 2 (Ig alpha-2 chain C region) (Ig alpha-2 chain C region BUT) (Ig alpha-2 chain C region LAN)                                IGHA2_HUMAN    AED5_deglycos  26165000
47 Immunoglobulin heavy constant alpha 2 (Ig alpha-2 chain C region) (Ig alpha-2 chain C region BUT) (Ig alpha-2 chain C region LAN)                                IGHA2_HUMAN    AI5             6706120
48 Immunoglobulin heavy constant alpha 2 (Ig alpha-2 chain C region) (Ig alpha-2 chain C region BUT) (Ig alpha-2 chain C region LAN)                                IGHA2_HUMAN    AI5_deglycos    5510820
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your desired result wrap `str_trunc` inside `str_wrap` like so:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  Protein.names = c(
    "Immunoglobulin heavy constant gamma 1 (Ig gamma-1 chain C region) (Ig gamma-1 chain C region EU) (Ig gamma-1 chain C region KOL) (Ig gamma-1 chain C region NIE)",
    "Immunoglobulin heavy constant mu (Ig mu chain C region) (Ig mu chain C region BOT) (Ig mu chain C region GAL) (Ig mu chain C region OU)"
  )
)

library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)

ggplot(df, aes(Protein.names)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_discrete(label = function(x) str_wrap(str_trunc(x, 60), width = 30)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, vjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect. A simpler solution than I anticipated. Much appreciated!